# Does Swift 4.2 has direct support for private setter that can be written via inheritance?

Tags: private, setter, swift4.2

I'd like to genuinely write in Swift the equivalent of the below code:

```
public class A {
    public fileprivate(set) a: Int = 0
}
```

So that I could do:

```
public class B: A {
    public func updateA() { a = 1 }
}
```

Of course without requiring any additional _a member.

Is it possible?

Side note: I'm aware of the existence of public private(set) but this prevent writing via inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

No, This is still not possible in swift, Also this is against the access control paradigm

If the private variables are able to set from the outside than they will not remain private you could use internal or public